# Cannot Boot Ubuntu after attempting to run a gparted

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted, boot-repair

My nice ubuntu VM on HyperV ran out of disk space.  I grew the VHDX file and then attempted to expand the boot partation but didn't get far.  Now I'm unable to properly boot; /dev/sda1 will not mount to /root.

Here is a the [boot-repair-disk log paste](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G3LlIwOu_iL9I0gJBtsCeZN7-M6DblEHRnJB81FVZPw/edit?usp=sharing).

Help please for this basic disk partitioning issue.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to expand the partition and interrupted the process? If you did then most probably you corrupted the partition and I doubt there's an easy way of fixing. You may try `testdisk`, but your best bet would probably be to re-install.